# Why are there suddenly a large amount of compiler errors in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

My code used to work fine, but I was working in my main controller's implementation when I noticed the code colors weren't right. When I hit run to have Xcode compile the code, I got every line of code as some kind of error in two of my header files. I have more header files, and I think they would have these weird errors too, but my guess is there was too many errors and it stopped.

For `@interface`, I get the error

```
Unexpected token after Objective-C string
```

For every other method, I get

```
Missing context for method declaration
```

For every other method, I get

Expected method body

[image]

Cleaning and rebuilding does not work.
Another strange thing is that the jump bar works for all of my headers and implentation, except for my main controllers implementation. It has the first pragma mark, and then just says NSLog().

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: missing curly bracket?

Comment: There is an error in a header file that is included several places. This is what version control is all about, commit often.

Comment: Also, check your prefix header. This may be happening before any of the #imports you have written in your source files.

Comment: @JDong you don't need a curly bracket. Anyways, adding it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @user1118321 I checked my prefix header (G-Clock-Prefix.pch, right?). I compared it to other ones online, and it looks fine.

Comment: @Zaph I checked all the headers in my project. Could it be on in the frameworks section?

Comment: @DrummerB cleaning and rebuilding doesn't help.

Comment: Have you run Disk Utility to see if maybe there's a problem with your disk? Maybe there are file I/O errors and it's confusing the compiler?

Comment: Is there a chance it could be one of my framework headers being changed in some wrong way? I was fascinated by the framework headers yesterday and I guess I could have accidentally changed something.

Comment: This is usually caused by a mucked-up header file.  Note that all that's necessary to foul things up is a missing `}` or `;` somewhere.

Comment: A framework header is not the problem, I reinstalled Xcode and the problem still lives on.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess based on little information:

There is an error in a header file that is included several places. This is what version control is all about, commit often.

If you think a framework header was changed then delete and re-install Xcode.